# How do you make a Zip/Jar in Java that will not contain the absolute pathname

Tags: java, path, jar, absolute

I'm generating a .jar file in Java, but the .jar contains an absolute pathname of where it is in the system (/tmp/tempXXX/foo instead of /foo).
The tree is like this:

```
.
|-- META-INF
|-|- ....
|-- tmp
|-|- tempXXX
|-|-|- foo
|-|-|- bar
```

Instead of this:

```
.
|-- META-INF
|-|- ....
|-- foo
|-- bar
```

Is it possible to fix this? Here is the function that makes it:

```
public static void add(File source, JarOutputStream target, String removeme)
        throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        File source2 = source;
        if (source.isDirectory())
        {
            String name = source2.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            if (!name.isEmpty())
            {
                if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                    name += "/";
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                target.putNextEntry(entry);
                target.closeEntry();
            }
            for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles())
                add(nestedFile, target, removeme);
            return;
        }

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source2.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        while (true)
        {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

The source2 variable was made for modifying the path, but when modifying, it gave an "Invalid .jar file" error.
The modification was this:

```
File source2 = new File(source.getPath().replaceAll("^" + removeme, ""));
```

Edit: It works now. Here is the new code if anyone is interested:

```
public static void add(File source, JarOutputStream target, String removeme)
        throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        File parentDir = new File(removeme);
        File source2 = new File(source.getCanonicalPath().substring(
                parentDir.getCanonicalPath().length() + 1,
                source.getCanonicalPath().length()));
        if (source.isDirectory())
        {
            String name = source2.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            if (!name.isEmpty())
            {
                if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                    name += "/";
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                target.putNextEntry(entry);
                target.closeEntry();
            }
            for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles())
                add(nestedFile, target, removeme);
            return;
        }

        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source2.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        while (true)
        {
            int count = in.read(buffer);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            target.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        target.closeEntry();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the relative path, you have to provide a relative path when calling JarEntry(name). Try removing the portion of the path up to the parent directory. So that would be something like,

```
File parentDir = "src";//dir from which you want the relative path

String relPath = source.getCanonicalPath()
                  .substring(parentDir.getCanonicalPath().length() + 1,
                             source.getCanonicalPath().length());

JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(relPath.replace(("\\", "/"));
...
```